# Diagnostic Accuracy: AUC vs cross-validation accuracy

Tags: cross-validation, roc, diagnostic

Can someone please explain the difference between the **diagnostic accuracy from the AUC model** vs **diagnostic accuracy in the below code**?

Note: I found the below code at the bottom of this forum/page: https://www.mihiretukebede.com/posts/2020-09-30-2020-09-30-plotting-model-coefficients-in-a-forest-plot/

```
(cv_logit <-  train(life_exp_cat ~ total_expenditure + 
             schooling + adult_mortality + infant_deaths + thinness_1_19_years +
            alcohol + status, data=life_exp_new, 
            method="glm", 
            trControl = trainControl(method="cv", number=10)))
```

Thank you all very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The code you show seems to fit some kind of generalized linear model (see the `method="glm"` bit, perhaps a logistic regression with a logit-link function) to the data and picks hyper-parameters / evaluates based on 10-fold cross-validation. It's not clear to me what metric is being optimized (per binary log-loss, perhaps accuracy, perhaps AUC).

In contrast, "AUC" is not a model. It means area under the curve and usually refers to in this context to the area under the [receiver-operator curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). I.e. it's [a metric of performance for binary classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) (but there's ways of looking at it with more categories than two) that is different from accuracy, which is just the proportion of cases that is correctly classified (i.e. number correctly classified divided by total number of cases).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have two follow-ups and would be amazing if we can discuss them: 1) I am looking to perform 10-fold cross validation. Is this how you would perform? If not, can you pls show me how you would do it? 2) If AUC is not about accuracy, can you pls explain what it is? I saw many papers referring to AUC as a test to assess "diagnostic accuracy" so I always believe AUC = accuracy?

Comment: 1) it's one way, assuming randomly selecting records of appropriate and you don't need to match a particular split 2) see the Wikipedia article, the two are of course not unrelated, but AuC only cares about correct ranking and accuracy mostly about whether predicted probabilities are correctly >0.5

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you pls share with me (e.g. code) how to obtain the cvAUC (cross-validation AUC)?